# RubyMotion and GameKit for turn-based game

Tags: game-center, gamekit, rubymotion, gkturnbasedmatch

I'm new to RubyMotion and although I found some good tutorial I cannot find anything about using RubyMotion with GameKit and GameCenter.

**The Context**: I have done a Tic-Tac-Toe game to learn RubyMotion. The game works fine locally, but I want to add multiplayer capabilities. That tutorial (http://www.raywenderlich.com/5480/beginning-turn-based-gaming-with-ios-5-part-1) in Obj-C is very comprehensive, but I failed to translate it to RM.

The app is very (very) simple, and very letterpresse"esque" (minus the design). It consists in a single tableview with started games and new game option, and the view for the Tic-Tac-Toe itself.

Does someone have experience with the GameKit framework in RubyMotion, or have found a tutorial on the subject? Actually, I cannot even make the first step of authenticating the user when the app loads (something like `GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer` leads to *uninitialized constant* and so on).

Thank you for your time!

P.S. It's my 3rd app (but first in RubyMotion) so I would think GameCenter and AppID, etc. are properly configured on iTunesConnect

Comment: Ok found it... I had to include the framework in the Rakefile. Still, if someone has a tutorial/sample code on using GameKit with Rubymotion I'm in!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found it... I had to include the framework in the Rakefile.